# how to change view's background color in viewForHeaderInSection when view gets tapped in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am using expandable table view. I used the below logic. If I tapped the section, I unable to change the view's back ground color. I have to change respective view's back ground color when it gets tapped. By my code, red color is blinking. I dont know why? Kindly guide me.

For Ex, I am having 5 sections means, it displays 5 views. I am unable to add tag for each and every view. I dont know how to do that. Kindly guide me.

My Coding:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
          var headerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, sideTableView.frame.size.width, 49))
            var layerLine = CALayer()
            layerLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: headerView.frame.size.height, width:  headerView.frame.size.width, height: 1)
            layerLine.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 220/255, green: 220/255, blue: 220/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
            headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 242/255, green: 242/255, blue: 242/255, alpha: 1.0)
            headerView.tag = section

            headerView.layer.addSublayer(layerLine)

            var headerString = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: sideTableView.frame.size.width-10, height: 30)) as UILabel
            headerString.text = sideTblData.objectAtIndex(section) as! NSString as String
            headerString.font = headerString.font.fontWithSize(15)
            headerView .addSubview(headerString)

            headerView.tag = section

            let headerTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer (target: self, action:"sectionHeaderTapped:")
            headerView .addGestureRecognizer(headerTapped)

            return headerView

    }

func sectionHeaderTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

if(cellClickedBool == true)
        {
            if(recognizer.view?.tag == 1)
            {
                recognizer.view?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() //RED COLOR IS BLINKING

            }

            cellClickedBool = false
        }
        else
        {
recognizer.view?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

            cellClickedBool = true
        }
}
```